# How to apply a regex on a column fetched from DB

Tags: db2, functions, regular-expression, regex

I am using IBM DB2.

So, I am retrieving a column named `SSN` from a table. I have to apply the following regex on that column:

```
([1-57-8][0-9]{2}
|0([1-9][0-9]
|[0-9][1-9])
|6([0-57-9][0-9]
|[0-9][0-57-9]))
([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])([1-9]\d{3}|\d[1-9]\d{2}|\d{2}[1-9]\d|\d{3}[1-9])
```

Someone suggested to me that I have to write a function/procedure in the query to validate that the `SSN` picked from the db follows this regex else it should not be stored in the result set of the query.

I don't know how to write a function or a procedure in SQL, can you please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex with UDFs (user-defined functions). What you need is to create a Function that will call a Regex library. After that, your SQL will call this Function to execute the Regex.

First, read the following [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html) as an example.

It says that you can create this Function as:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION regex1(pattern VARCHAR(2048), string CLOB(10M)) 
    RETURNS INTEGER 
    SPECIFIC regexSimple 
    EXTERNAL NAME 'regexUdf!regexpSimple' 
    LANGUAGE C 
    PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL 
    DETERMINISTIC 
    NOT FENCED 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
    NO SQL 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
    ALLOW PARALLEL;
```

The article also shows the C library code and indicates how you can compile it.

After that, you may use your function like that:

```
SELECT c1, str 
FROM   strTable 
WHERE  regex1('#\s*\w+', str) = 1;
```

With that in mind, I suggest that you Google a little more to find a more complete Regex library to resolve your problem.

**Edited**: as suggested by [Chris Aldrich](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1342/chris-aldrich), you may consider on running this function as fenced for safety. Read more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18339/stored-procedures-best-practices-fenced-or-unfenced).

Comment: I would vote that the function is run FENCED since it calls out to a library. If the library ever crashes it has the possibility of endangering the DB2 engine if it is running NOT FENCED.